# How to find out windows service status which is running on another server from one server?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Normally when it is required to know the one of the service status in the existing server means it is easy by from finding the result from the servicecontroller by pasted below code:

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("servicename");

if  ((sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)) ||
 (sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)))
{
  // Start the service if the current status is stopped.
  sc.Start();
}
```

Here i would like to know the service status of another machine, how can i find out the result can any one able to guide me on this scenario.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4242/Command-Line-Windows-Services-Manager , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866104/c-sharp-service-status-on-remote-machine

Answer (score -1):

There's another constructor of ServiceController that takes the machine name as a second parameter. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssbk2tf3.aspx

Have you tried it?