# Restarting a custom service in a remote machine running under specific user account C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, cmd

I'm running a windows service in a server and I now I want it to restart it from a local machine by a software tool I developed by C#.

I tried using "sc" but it says "The service is not installed" and I think it is because it is actually not a windows default service but a custom one.

Could anyone help me out with how to do it?

P.S. sc also said I don't have enough privilege because the service is running under administrative privilege in the server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: se.exe will work for any correctly configured service.  You can use `ServiceController()` to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: I edited the question. I tried doing so, it didn't work because the service is running under another user account. @AlexK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following to start and stop a service in a remote location

```js
ServiceController insServiceController = new ServiceController("Your Service Name", "IP address of the remote server");

insServiceController.Start();
insServiceController.Stop();
```

Comment: I edited the question. The service is running under another user account with admin privilege. This solution won't work. @Ozan

Comment: In that case you can maybe refer to following: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/svcmgr.aspx?display=Print

Comment: Tried that solution too. No success. Although I couldn't figure out the domain thing in the parameters though. @Ozan

Comment: Is the remote machine in a domain? Also is the service is on a domain user account or local account? If user is a local account then you should provide the domain parameter as the network name of the server

Comment: The remote machine doesn't have any domain info in the network properties. Only group info (which is workgroup). The account I have in there has administrative privilege. Also note, it is not a default installed windows service but a custom one. I developed that service myself. @Ozan

Comment: Have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6912610/4848251

Comment: Yes, like I said, I don't have anything to pass for the argument 'domain'. @Ozan

Comment: If you have access to remote machine, open command prompt and type SET then find the key LOGONSERVER. Try to pass that value (without backslashes) as the domain input parameter

Comment: Great. SET discovered the USERDOMAIN info. I passed it through the code-project solution, and it is giving me "Cannot open <service-name> on computer <computer-name>" :( @Ozan

Comment: We are progressing :) Are you providing displayed name of the service?

Comment: Displayed name. But it also comes with a space character so I used double quote with the service name. @Ozan

Comment: On remote machine, click Start > Run and type services.msc
Find your custom service and right click on it, choose Properties. Get the value at the top of the window for Service Name which should be different than the display name. Try passing that info

Comment: Check the screenshot. The display name also has a space

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/BIv0I

Comment: Let me try this... I'll get back to you

Comment: After starting impersonation, can you run the following and check if you see your service in the list ?

ServiceController[] _Services = ServiceController.GetServices("IP or NetworkName");
                    foreach (var service in _Services)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Display name : " + service.DisplayName);
                    }

Comment: It gave me "Cannot open Service Control Manager on Computer <server-ip>. This operation might require other privileges"